# Access to Object property using computed method in vue 3 veux shows undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vuex4

I get undefined when I try to render the values of the computed property
in the template using its property  `{{todo[0]['title']}}` but `{{todo[0]]}}` renders the whole objects. I want to be able to render a  todo using it property. Any assistance is well appreciated

```js
const {
  createApp,
  ref,
  computed,
  onMounted
} = Vue;
const {
  createStore
} = Vuex;
const store = createStore({
  state: {
    alltodos: []
  },
  mutations: {
    setTodos(state, todo) {
      (state.alltodos) = todo
    }
  },
  getters: {
    allTodoGetters(state) {
      const sta = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state));
      return sta
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async fetchTodos({
      commit
    }) {
      const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
      commit('setTodos', response.data);
    },
  }
});
const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    let alltodos = computed(() => store.getters["allTodoGetters"]);
    onMounted(() => {
      store.dispatch('fetchTodos')
    })
    return {
      alltodos
    }
  }
});
app.mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.2.30/vue.global.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@4.0.0/dist/vuex.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.26.1/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPh3uwgU5qEMipS/VOmRqynnMXGGSRv+72H/N260MQeXZIK4PG48401Bsby9Nq5P5fz7hy5UGNmC/W1Z51h2GQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(todo, index)  of alltodos" :key="index">{{todo[0]}}</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show first item from array try like following snippet:

```js
const {
  createApp,
  ref,
  computed,
  onMounted
} = Vue;
const {
  createStore
} = Vuex;
const store = createStore({
  state: {
    alltodos: []
  },
  mutations: {
    setTodos(state, todo) {
      (state.alltodos) = todo
    }
  },
  getters: {
    allTodoGetters(state) {
                                                //  return just the state you want
      const sta = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.alltodos));
      return sta
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async fetchTodos({
      commit
    }) {
      const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos');
      commit('setTodos', response.data);
    },
  }
});
const app = createApp({
  setup() {
    let alltodos = computed(() => store.getters["allTodoGetters"]);
    onMounted(() => {
      store.dispatch('fetchTodos')
    })
    return {
      alltodos
    }
  }
});
app.mount("#app")
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.2.30/vue.global.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@4.0.0/dist/vuex.global.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.26.1/axios.min.js" integrity="sha512-bPh3uwgU5qEMipS/VOmRqynnMXGGSRv+72H/N260MQeXZIK4PG48401Bsby9Nq5P5fz7hy5UGNmC/W1Z51h2GQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div id="app">                           
  <div v-for="(todo, index) in alltodos"  :key="index">
           <!--  show property you want -->
    <div v-for="(property, i) in todo">{{ property }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please why this seems to be working. how to i get all title in the object. the api contains 200 items

Comment: @Eaimie hey mate, check now pls

Comment: please i want to loop over the whole object of array and not to render the first items.  This is just an abstraction of the problem

Comment: @Eaimie please can you show me desired result?

Comment: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos       i want to loop over this api and displays all the title in a table

Comment: check now please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243164/discussion-between-eaimie-and-nikola-pavicevic).